# How to Navigate fixing a part of screen in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, navigation

I have an material app with 2 containers in a column and my second container should be fixed, when I press a button in first container it should take to other frame(only data in top container should change),in the app which I am designing Data in second container is fixed data in first container will be changing. So basically bottom part of my app is fixed and transition should be top part of screen.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is unclear, please post code.
From what I understand you'd like the top Container's content to change.
What I would suggest is creating a custom Stateful widget instead of this container,then you can change the content by calling setState(),and changing the relevant values.